# Утилита для загрузки файлов по HTTP/S с поддержкой SOCKS-proxy

Tags: windows, консоль

Есть такая утилита - wget, которая позволяет в скриптах загружать файлы по разным протоколам. Но у неё есть один недостаток: она не позволяет (или я не нашёл как) использовать socks-proxy при загрузке по http/s.

В связи с этим есть вопрос: кто-нибудь знает [консольное] приложение для Windows [x64], которое умеет загружать файлы по протоколам HTTP, HTTPS, [FTP], используя прокси-сервер SOCKS5 с авторизацией, с возможностью использования из командной строки?

P.S: в [..] указан желательный, но не обязательный функционал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если чем-то не устраивает wget, в запасе всегда есть curl:

```
curl -x socks5://[user:password@]proxyhost[:port]/ url
curl --socks5 192.168.1.254:3099 https://example.com/
```

Всегда свежие билды под Windows можно взять тут: https://curl.se/windows/

Comment: Да, подошло, спасибо.